# Automatically redirects my application from HTTP to HTTPS in Google Chrome Browser

Tags: asp.net, https, url-rewriting, web-config, web.config-transform

I added the below code in web.config, for forwarding the URL from HTTP to HTTPS.

```
 <rewrite xdt:Transform="Insert">
  <rules>
    <!-- Redirects users to HTTPS if they try to access with HTTP -->
    <rule
      name="Force HTTPS"
      stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" ignoreCase="true"/>
      </conditions>
      <action
        type="Redirect"
        url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"
       /> <!--redirectType="Permanent"-->
    </rule>
  </rules>

</rewrite>
```

It's working fine, after some time I removed the above code from web.config but still my Google Chrome browser will automatically redirects my URL form http to https whenever my application runs in my local machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Chrome caches redirects. Clear cache after making changes to web config or at least keep developer console opened with "Disable cache" options checked in the Network tab.

Comment: when ever "Disable cache" it works for me but whenever I clear the cache it's won't work.

Comment: I know, it is iritating. BTW, I found this plugin for testing redirects useful: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redirect-path/aomidfkchockcldhbkggjokdkkebmdll